# Book for Calculus

Tags: soft-question

I'm interested in Integration. Of late, I've been exposed to several problems on Summations, Integration and Special Functions, as well as the knowledge of theorems such as the Dominated Convergence Theorem, Fubini's Theorem and so on so forth. These problems require greater knowledge of Calculus than what I presently know.

I have learnt Calculus from the following book:

- [**Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences**](http://www.amazon.in/Mathematical-Methods-Physical-Sciences-Mary/dp/8126508108/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1435492344&sr=1-1&keywords=mathematical+methods+in+the+physical+sciences) by Mary L Boas

I learnt some Calculus of One Variable and so now have been trying Multi Variable Calculus. I'm comfortable with Partial Differentiation,  and to an extent Hyperbolic Trigonometry too. I have not studied Linear Algebra before.

I want to start with Complex methods of Integration such as Contour Integration.

Could somebody suggest books from where I could study?

Comment: Calculus by Thomas and Finney....

Comment: I'm in a similar situation; thank you for the question! May I ask how old you are?

Comment: @BetterWorld Sir?

I beg to differ; I too turned 16 previous November :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A delicious classic would be "The Theory of Functions" by Titchmarsh. Despite being old (1939), it is very modern in its rigour, fear not! You may find it [freely available](https://archive.org/details/TheTheoryOfFunctions) on the internet, it is no longer subjected to any copyright.

Comment: @BetterWorld: Instead of searching for books every two days, better arm yourself with lots of patience. One cannot become fluent in English in just a few days; similarly, don't expect do understand complex analysis quickly. As an advice, start reading chapter 3 in Titchmarsh's book and, as soon as you do not understand something, search for it back in the previous chapters. Also, you may safely skip some sub-chapters ("Infinite products", Double series" - most of chapter 1 will not be needed).